# running bash command from python shell

Tags: python, bash

I want to run a bash command from python shell.
my bash is:

```
grep -Po "(?<=<cite>).*?(?=</cite>)" /tmp/file1.txt | awk -F/ '{print $1}' | awk '!x[$0]++' > /tmp/file2.txt
```

what I tried is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import commands
commands.getoutput('grep ' + '-Po ' +  '\"\(?<=<dev>\).*?\(?=</dev>\)\" ' + '/tmp/file.txt ' + '| ' + 'awk \'!x[$0]++\' ' + '> ' + '/tmp/file2.txt')
```

But I don't have any result.

Thank you

Comment: `commands` is deprecated in favor of `subprocess`. That said, what you're doing here -- invoking a shell, rather than doing the processing in Python or setting up a pipeline natively yourself -- is considered poor practice anyhow (and, if not done very carefully, can lead to shell injection attacks if handling user-provided data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid splitting your arguments and worrying about pipes, you can use the `shell=True` option:

```
cmd = "grep -Po \"(?<=<dev>).*?(?=</dev>)\" /tmp/file.txt | awk -F/ '{print $1}' | awk '!x[$0]++' > file2.txt"
out = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

This will run a subshell which will understands all your directives, including "|" for piping, ">" for redirection. If you do not do this, these symbols normally parsed by the shell will just be passed to grep program.

Otherwise, you have to create the pipes yourself. For example (untested code below):

```
grep_p = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-Po", "(?<=<dev>).*?(?=</dev>)", "/tmp/file.txt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
awk_p = subprocess.Popen(["awk", "-F/", "'{print $1}'"], stdin = grep_p.stdout)
file2_fh = open("file2.txt", "w")
awk_p_2 = subprocess.Popen(["awk", "!x[$0]++", stdout = file2_fh, stdin = awk_p.stdout)
awk_p_2.communicate()
```

However, you're missing the point of python if you are doing this. You should instead look into the re module: `re.match`, `re.sub`, `re.search`, though I'm not familiar enough with awk to translate your commands.

Comment: since `shell=True`, the command will be run in a subshell, so all the shell directives, including ">" to redirect stdout to a file, should work as expected. Are you saying `file2.txt` doesn't get created?

Comment: no...It is working...but there is a problem..I have `sed` command...may I update my question and then you assist? Thanks

Comment: sure. Though you should understand the pattern so you can do these pipes yourself.

Comment: @nettux443 instead of manually creating these tedious pipes, we can write a function to handle them. See my latest answer, let me know how it works.

Answer (score 3):

The recommend way to run system commands in python is to use the module [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

```
import subprocess

a=['grep' ,'-Po', '"(?<=<dev>).*?(?=</dev>)"','/tmp/file.txt']
b=['awk', '-F/', '"{print $1}"'] 
c=["awk", '"!x[$0]++"']

p1 = subprocess.Popen(a,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(b,stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p3 = subprocess.Popen(c,stdin=p2.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
p2.stdout.close()
out,err=p3.communicate()
print out
```

The point of creating pipes between each subprocess is for security and debugging reasons. Also it makes the code much clearer in terms, which process gets input and sends output to.

Answer (score 1):

Let us write a simple function to easily deal with these messy pipes for us:

```
def subprocess_pipes (pipes, last_pipe_out = None):
    import subprocess
    from subprocess  import PIPE
    last_p = None
    for cmd in pipes:
        out_pipe = PIPE if not (cmd==pipes[-1] and last_pipe_out) else open(last_pipe_out, "w")
        cmd = cmd if isinstance(cmd, list) else cmd.split(" ")
        in_pipe = last_p.stdout if last_p else None
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = out_pipe, stdin = in_pipe)
        last_p = p
    comm = last_p.communicate()
    return comm
```

Then we run,

```
subprocess_pipes(("ps ax", "grep python"), last_pipe_out = "test.out.2")
```

The result is a "test.out.2" file with the contents of piping "ps ax" into "grep python".

In your case,

```
a = ["grep", "-Po", "(?<=<cite>).*?(?=</cite>)", "/tmp/file1.txt"]
b = ["awk", "-F/", "{print $1}"]
c = ["awk", "!x[$0]++"]

subprocess_pipes((a, b, c),  last_pipe_out = "/tmp/file2.txt")
```

Comment: Nice! The only beef I have is the use of `string.split()` -- too easy for folks to try to pass in filenames via string substitution. Better to encourage passing in arguments as an array to start with. Still, this is a very cute piece of code; +1.

Answer (score 0):

The `commands` module is obsolete now.
If you don't actually need the output of your command you can use

```
import os

exit_status = os.system("your-command")
```

Otherwise you can use

```
import suproccess

out, err = subprocess.Popen("your | commands", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True).communicate()
```

Note: for your command you send stdout to `file2.txt` so I wouldn't expect to see anything in `out` you will however still see error messages on stderr which will go into `err`

Comment: In my case your answer with import os is better because I am writing output to a file..

Comment: this answer will not write output to file2.txt as the OP needs. In fact, it won't even create the pipes appropriately. The latter "awk" commands and alll their arguments will all just be passed as arguments to "grep" (which will get really confused). See my answer for an example of how to properly pipe various commands, and to write to file, using subprocess.

Comment: @erjoalgo Edited. Seems to work for me now.. But yours and bort's answers are better.

Answer (score 0):

you must use

```
import os 
os.system(command)
```

Comment: "Must" is a strong word, especially when the `os.system()` documentation says you should use `subprocess` instead.

Answer (score -2):

I think what you are looking for is something like:
`ubprocess.check_output(same as popen arguments, **kwargs)` , use it the same way you would use a `popen` command , it should show you the output of the program that's being called.

For more details here is a link: http://freefilesdl.com/how-to-call-a-shell-command-from-python/